# WPF: binding to a dependency property

Tags: wpf, binding

I am following a tutorial [here](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/wpf-tutorial-binding-validation-rules). which shows a basic example on how to bind to a dependency property.

```
<Binding ElementName="This" Path="IPAddress" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
```

where "This" is the name of the current window:

```
<Window x:Class="SOTCBindingValidation.Window1" x:Name="This"
```

whenever i try to do something like this, i keep getting the same error:

***Cannot find source for binding with reference 'ElementName=GridControlControl1'. BindingExpression:Path=IPAddress; DataItem=null; target element is 'TextBox' (Name='AddressBox'); target property is 'Text' (type 'String')***

my code:

```
 <UserControl x:Class="WpfGridtest.GridControl" x:Name="GridControlControl1" ... />
    <TextBox x:Name="AddressBox">
        <TextBox.Text>
            <Binding ElementName="GridControlControl1" Path="IPAddress" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
        </Binding>
    </TextBox.Text>
</TextBox>
```

codebehind:

```
partial class GridControl : UserControl
     public static readonly DependencyProperty IPAddressProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("IPAddress", typeof(string), typeof(GridControl), new UIPropertyMetadata("1.1.1.1"));

        public string IPAddress
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(IPAddressProperty); }
            set { SetValue(IPAddressProperty, value); }
        }
```

it's almost like something changed in .Net 4.0?

Comment: i just repro the same thing what you have done, i did't seem to get any error.

Comment: what framework are you using ?

Comment: ok, thanks for conforming that this works.. something must be wrong with my setup.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It depends on what you want. I'll try to offer a complete answer. One way to guarantee better success with this syntax is to use VS2010's [XAML Binding Builder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/wpfsldesigner/how-to-enable-using-the-binding-builder-in-wpf-and-silverlight-applications), which is how I assembled the syntax you're about to see.

**If you want an element of the UserControl to display your IPAddress dependency property,** (which looks like it's defined correctly to me), use this syntax within the body of the UserControl's markup:

```
   <TextBlock Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, 
                             AncestorType={x:Type my:GridControl}, 
                             AncestorLevel=1}, 
              Path=IPAddress}" />
```

Most XAML binding examples use this syntax rather than the more verbose hierarchical XML:

```
        <TextBlock>
            <TextBlock.Text>
                <Binding Path="IPAddress">
                    <Binding.RelativeSource>
                        <RelativeSource Mode="FindAncestor" 
                                        AncestorType="{x:Type my:GridControl}"
                                        AncestorLevel="1" 
                        />
                    </Binding.RelativeSource>
                </Binding>
            </TextBlock.Text>
        </TextBlock>
```

...but both kinds of syntax produce the same results. *Note here that the `AncestorType` is the class name of your UserControl, not the `x:Name` you would supply when using the UserControl in other markup.*

**Suppose you have a UI element in markup outside your UserControl, and you want access to your DependencyProperty for that other control**. The markup looks something like this:

```
    <my:GridControl 
       x:Name="GridControl1" IPAddress="192.168.1.1" />
    <TextBox Text="{Binding ElementName=GridControl1, Path=IPAddress}"/>
```

Or, alternatively, this:

```
    <TextBox>
        <TextBox.Text>
            <Binding ElementName="GridControl1" Path="IPAddress"/>
        </TextBox.Text>
    </TextBox>
```

*Note here that this time you're using the `x:Name` property of the GridControl rather than the class name, and that you refer to it as an `ElementName`, and not an "Ancestor".* In both cases, though, the `Path` is the declared name of the DependencyProperty you defined.

Comment: thank you. although it is the same thing me and Andreas have already, but i appreciate your post, and xaml builder link.

Comment: You're welcome. Binding syntax is tough; it only gets evaluated at runtime and the errors are nearly impossible to interpret, in my opinion.

About the only thing I can think of other than my general answer is that there is a missing right-bracket character after `Path=IPAddress`, but the XAML editor would have caught that right away...

That, and I used "FrameworkPropertyMetadata" rather than "UIPropertyMetadata" to set up the DP, but I don't think that's a difference with a distinction either.

Answer (score 3):

Try using RelativeSource:

```
<TextBox>
  <TextBox.Text>
    <Binding Path="IPAddress">
      <Binding.RelativeSource>
        <RelativeSource
           Mode="FindAncestor"
           AncestorType="{x:Type UserControl}"
           AncestorLevel="1"
        />
      </Binding.RelativeSource>
    </Binding>
  </TextBox.Text>
</TextBox>
```

Instead of `{x:Type UserControl}`you could insert your actual type there, i.e.:

```
<TextBox>
  <TextBox.Text>
    <Binding Path="IPAddress">
      <Binding.RelativeSource>
        <RelativeSource xmlns:my="clr-namespace:WpfGridtest"
           Mode="FindAncestor"
           AncestorType="{x:Type my:GridControl}"
           AncestorLevel="1"
        />
      </Binding.RelativeSource>
    </Binding>
  </TextBox.Text>
</TextBox>
```

Comment: thanks, 
i've actually tried seemingly every possible iteration of FindAncestor before resorting to DependecyProperty approach.. definitely x:Type CustomControl

Comment: Did it work now then? Or is there anything wrong with the FindAncestor approach?

Comment: had no luck with FindAncestor. i wasted hours on friday with that approach. tried adding it to the top Window, as well as Control, referencing it as x:Type .. keep getting the same non informative error messages.. "unable to find ancestor blah blah"

Comment: When I'm at home later I will try to reproduce. Here I don't have an appropriate IDE (and even time) for testing. We should really be able to accomplish this... :) do not give up!

Comment: i can't give up! have to finish my project somehow :)

Comment: It should've been UserControl... it was the heat, forgive me.